# 'Screen Time' fails to report children's usage correctly due to an extra, non-existence device

Tags: iphone, icloud, screen-time

The `Screen Time` function is supposed to be able to report children's usage to their guardians.

However it fails to report a correct figure for my situation.

Here is the main screen time for my kid 'A':

[image]

Here it reports 16s of usage. It is definitely not corrected.

When I checked the 'Devices' I can see three drives are shown:

[image]

The 'iPhone' device is non-device. Kid 'A' only has access to an iphone and an iPad. The 'iPhone' is probably the old phone that has since been replaced by a newer one 'A's iphone'

I have already cleaned up the device records on A's icloud account a few day ago. However it is not reflected on my phone.

Is there any way I can remove the spurious device from my end?